# The Feynman propagator and the $i\epsilon$ prescription

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, propagator, wick-rotation

The Feynman propagator is usually represented in the i-epsilon form and texts solve the integral in this form (as opposed to doing the Feynman (time-ordered) contour on the real axis). Restricting ourselves to the integration over the $k_0$ component of the integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{i e^{-i t k_0}}{(2 \pi )
   \left(\left(\text{i$\epsilon $}+k_0-\omega _k\right)
   \left(-\text{i$\epsilon $}+k_0-\omega _k\right)\right)} \, dk_0
$$

In doing the integral using the contour instead of using the i-epsilon displacement of the poles, I arrive at a slightly different answer. In trying to find my error, I resorted to a simpler integral, the Dirichlet integral

$$
\int_0^{\infty }
   \frac{\sin(a x)}{x}
   \, dx=\frac{\pi }{2}
$$
This is easily solved using a contour over or under the pole at the origin (depending on the sign of $a$).  But in solving the integral using the i-epsilon prescription (for example if the pole is displaced upward/downward on the imaginary axis to $\pm i\epsilon$):
$$
\int_0^{\infty }
   \frac{\sin(a x)}{x \mp i\epsilon} \, dx
$$

I don't get $\frac{\pi }{2}$ as the answer (the pole is inside or outside the contour depending on whether the contour closes in the upper half plane or lower half plane). For one choice of displacement I arrive at $\pi$ and for the other I arive at $0$ (they average to the correct answer!?) Where is my error?

In response to the replies (so far):
The pole is a simple removable pole and the integral is undefined at the origin since the integrand is 0/0. One way to evaluate this integral, is to first convert to exponential form

$$\frac{1}{2} \text{Im} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   \frac{e^{\text{iax}}}{x\pm \text{i$\epsilon
   $}} \, dx$$

if "a" is positive for example, you need to close the contour in the upper half plane.  But you get different results if the pole is displaced downward (integral=0) or upward (integral=$\pi$).

Comment: Did you apply the Jordan's lemma to see whether close the integral from above or below? For most integrals, you can only close it one way.

Comment: Why do you have a pole at origin? $\sin(ax)\sim ax$ when $x$ is small. So $\frac{sin(ax)}{x}\to a$ when $x\to 0$, which is finite.

Comment: You can't really close the pole anywhere with $\sin (x)$ functions because it blows up for $x$ with large imaginary argument. Instead you can convert it to an integral involving only $e^{iax}$ function. We have that $ \int _0 ^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm d x = \frac{-i}{2} \int_{- \infty} ^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} \mathrm d x$. This integral can be correctly evaluated with residue theorem.